# Make an array based on common value

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array with following structure. It has some repeated values which I need to sort based the correct manufacturer and model.

```
2 => array:3 [
    "id_111" => "ALFA ROMEO"
    "id_112" => "4C"
    "id_8702" => "P"
]
3 => array:3 [
    "id_111" => "ALFA ROMEO"
    "id_112" => "GIULIA"
    "id_8702" => "D"
]
4 => array:3 [
    "id_111" => "ALFA ROMEO"
    "id_112" => "GIULIA"
    "id_8702" => "U"
]
5 => array:3 [
    "id_111" => "ALFA ROMEO"
    "id_112" => "GIULIETTA"
    "id_8702" => "D"
]
6 => array:3 [
    "id_111" => "ALFA ROMEO"
    "id_112" => "GIULIETTA"
    "id_8702" => "U"
]
7 => array:3 [
    "id_111" => "ALFA ROMEO"
    "id_112" => "STELVIO"
    "id_8702" => "D"
]
```

From this query, I have to make the structured array like below:

```
manufacturers: [
0: {
    name: "ALFA ROMEO", 
    models: [
        0: {
            name: "4C",
            ids: [
                0: { name: "p" }
            ]
        },
        1: {
            name: "GIULIA",
            ids: [
                0: {name: "D"},
                1: {name: "U"}

            ]
        },
        2: {
            name: "GIULIETTA",
            ids: [
                0: {name: "U"},
                1: {name: "D"}
            ]
        }

    ]
}
1: {}
```

]

So far I have tried following code. But For some reason, I am kind of lost.

```
    $data = array();

    foreach ($records as $record) {
        $id1 = $record["id_111"];
        $data["manufacturer"] = array();
        if (!in_array("id1", $data["manufacturer"])) {
            $data["manufacturer"] = array(
                "name" => $id1
            );
        }
        $id2 = $record["id_112"];

        $data["manufacturer"][] = array("name" => $id2);
    }
```

Can anybody please help me. Thank You.

Comment: what is `ids` values?

Comment: ids are id_8702

Comment: like this: `ids: [
                    0: {"id_8702":  "D"},
                    1: {"id_8702" : "U"}
                ]`

Comment: yes those are the ids.@TsaiKoga

Comment: @TsaiKoga I have tried following code.         foreach ($records as $record) {
            $id1 = $record["id_111"];
            $id2 = $record["id_112"];

            if (!array_key_exists($id1, $results)) {
                $results[$id1][] = array(
                    "name" => $id1,
                );
            }

            if (!array_key_exists($id2, $results[$id1])) {
                $results[$id1][$id2][] = array(
                    "name" => $id2,
                );
            }
        } The structure is same as I want but instead of key i want to show manufacture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a groupBy function:

```php
function groupBy($items, $key)
{
    $array = array();
    foreach($items as $item) {
       foreach($item as $k => $v) {
           if($key == $k) $array[$v] []= $item;
       }
    }
    return $array;
}
```

and then

```php
$names = groupBy($records, 'id_111');
$name_array = [];
foreach($names as $name => $name_items) {
    $models = groupBy($name_items, 'id_112');
    $model_array = [];
    foreach($models as $model => $model_items) {
       $ids = array_map(function($item) {
          return ['name' => $item['id_8702']];
       },$model_items);
       $model_array []= ['name' => $model, 'ids' => $ids];
    }
    $name_array []= ['name' => $name, 'models' => $model_array];
}

$results = ['manufacturers' => $name_array];
```